# Conflict between J2EE Server & .Net Server on a Single System

Tags: java, c#, .net, jakarta-ee

**Spec** 
OS : Windows 8 Enterprise Version.
Jdk : 1.8

For Some Company resource-crunch reason, we have a been provided with a
single Server (Hardware) for Developers of  `java` & `net` to be used for
Integration Testing purpose.

**Task** : To install a (J2EE)Web-logic Server  &  .Net Framework (latest) on the system.

**Question**  : Will there be any Conflict between  `Java` vs `C#` in responding  when used simultaneously ???`

Comment: Do you know how to configure both servers to listen on different interfaces and/or different ports? I'm not certain, but this question may be a better fit on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/). Also, it's [WebLogic](https://www.oracle.com/middleware/weblogic/index.html).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about server administration and not about programming and this question is too basic to be migrated to Server Fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot depends on the hardware resources available. That is to say, the specs, cpu, ram, etc and number of concurrent requests. Otherwise there should be no conflicts since weblogic server ports can be configured during creation of servers and the default admin port runs on 7001. The IIS default port is 80. So simultaneous requests to both applications deployed on the single machine won't conflict and will be processed in their own threads. The only requirement being the hardware (CPU,RAM more specifically) be of decent specs. I am assuming that since it is a company provided server for Integration testing, it should be decent enough.

Comment: Guys  ...... I need some reviews on the  "Conflict between Java vs C# in responding when used simultaneously"   NOT PORT/CPU/RAM Configuration.  I am trying to get to know the thread / Os behavior and other such Info

Comment: Karthik, there will be no conflicts as far as language constraints go. Even if you had to run java, php, C#, python, perl, apps and there were simultaneous requests for each of them, the server would process these in their own separate processes without any conflicts. An operating system is designed to handled all this. The reason I spoke about RAM/CPU, etc because these can matter a lot while performance testing, and sometimes shortage of these resources can lead to delayed application responses which lead to a false belief that something might be wrong with the application itself.